# How to install Jupyter Lab/Notebook on Windows 10?

Tags: r, windows, jupyter-irkernel

I have been using R/Python and Jupyter Lab/Notebook on Macbook. In my new job, I need to install and run these applications on Windows 10.

I have Python, pip, Jupyter, R4.1 & RStudio installed manually (not through Anaconda). I try to execute step 2/3: Making the kernel available to Jupyter based on [installation guide](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/#binary-panel). I got error message in R Console.

```
> IRkernel::installspec()
Error in IRkernel::installspec() : 
  jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 127.
In addition: Warning message:
In system2("jupyter", c("kernelspec", "--version"), FALSE, FALSE) :
  '"jupyter"' not found
```

Appreciate your advice.

Comment: Just go to https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual when you install it, during installation, make sure you check the PATH option, it will go red, but don't worry. That will allow you to run Jupyter Notebook anywhere in the command terminal. Now go to your command terminal, and type in `conda install -c r r-irkernel` for R. Then type `JUPYTER NOTEBOOK` in command terminal.

Comment: If you want Jupyter Labs, just search on your computer for Anaconda Navigator, open it, and it will load up a screen, which will show options to run R, Labs, Notebook etc.

Comment: @MichaelRSF I installed everything manually, not through Anaconda.

Comment: Well I recommend just installing Anaconda, and then following the above steps. Much simpler.

Comment: @MichaelRSF tq for advice on Anaconda. I actually have been using manual installation with Macbook througout my learning journey, hence forgot about Anaconda. It is indeed more convenient way to install Python & R. However, I am almost there, so I will not start the entire installation over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if jupyter is in your user/system path. A quick way to check is by running jupyter in the command line, you could use powershell commandline:

```
Get-Command jupyter

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     jupyter.exe                                        0.0.0.0    C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Local\Programs\...
```

If it's not there, then you can add to your system/user path and check with new  instance of commandline again.

Comment: here is what i got...```PS C:\Users\kamsiong.ong> Get-Command jupyter
Get-Command : The term 'jupyter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet....```. please guide me to add user path.

Comment: @OngK.S jupyter binary should be inside script folder of python path.  In my case its, C:\Users\shres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\jupyter -h

Comment: Yo need to add both base python folder and Scripts folder to your path.

To add to your path, type path in windows search, you should see **Edit environment variables for your account**. Environment variable windows will open. Click on the path from the user variable option. Hit edit and add both path. Now take new powershell isntance and check again.

Comment: with `Get-Command python3 | fl *`, I got this path `C:\Users\kamsiong.ong\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe`. I check in windows explorer, python3 doesn't seem to be installed in a folder. Should i proceed to add the path?

Comment: @OngK.S, you can delete the file, C:\Users\kamsiong.ong\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe as it points to windows store. If you've not installed python, you can install winpython or from official download.

Comment: it is weird, i already have Python 3.9 installed but `Get-Command` just couldn't locate the path.

Comment: I manage to add the PATH variables for python and jupyter. Thanks for your help.